# OSGi EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm confused about how to create my Java EE application. I not sure about the terms, but let's say I want to convert usual java app to OSGi(war file)

I can use GlassFish "Hybrid bundles" are they something Glassfish specific? If I understand correctly the Java EE services are just offered in form of OSGi services.

Can I use i.e. WAB written for use with Glassfish in plain Apache Felix? Are GlassFish EE OSGi services something Apache Aries is offering? So I can either run in Glassfish or in Felix with Apache Aries?

I'm interested in compatibility. Will bundles written for Glassfish run in Jboss OSGi as well? Are the WABs common OSGi concepts?

Comment: JBoss OSGi doesn't exist anymore, from Wildfly on, no more support for OSGi apps in JBoss.

Comment: Does it mean that Java EE guys don't want to have OSGi in their backyard. Are they proposing that if you want OSGi you should run OSGi runtime on top of EE servers? If you will do this you will not have connection to EE services at all or do they offer any solution?

Comment: @AchimNierbeck: JBoss OSGi does still exist, RedHat officially dropped it but there have been some community releases recently. Anyway, even at times when RedHat was still putting resources into JBoss OSGi and the AS/WildFly integration, the user experience was never quite satisfactory IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

The [OSGi Enterprise specification](https://osgi.org/download/r5/osgi.enterprise-5.0.0.pdf) defines a certain level of interoperability between Java EE and OSGi.

The relationship is a bit one-sided. Java EE does not officially recognize OSGi, whereas OSGi EE directly references a number of individual specifications under the Java EE umbrella (e.g. JPA, JDBC, JTA, Servlet, JNDI) .

Unfortunately, those OSGi specifications that extend a given Java EE specification often do not cover the latest EE version, or they impose some additional restrictions.

Many important EE specifications have no OSGi counterpart at all (like CDI, JAX-RS, JAX-WS, JMS, Bean Validation, JCA).

You can find implementations of (subsets of) the OSGi Enterprise specifications in Apache Aries, Eclipse Gemini and OPS4J. Some of these projects provide additional functionality that is not covered by the OSGi EE specs.

Java EE servers with OSGi support (like GlassFish 3/4 and JBoss AS 7.0/7.1) do have their own ways that do not necessarily comply with the OSGi Enterprise specs and most likely are not interoperable.

Comment: That is kind of sad. In my eyes I see the OSGi is not getting the drive it deserves. What is the place of Apache Aries in this?

Comment: oh, almost forgot. If you use Apache Karaf, it'll contain most of those enterprise features pre-installed, or easy to install for users. So that one was missing on the list of OSGi Enterprise ready application servers ;-)